# ASP.NET refering an image or asp file in a Strongly Typed fashion

Tags: c#, asp.net, strong-typing

Many times we need to refer another file on the server. Whether it's just an image, or another asp page. For example:

```
 if (success)
 {
    img1.ImageUrl = "RightArrow.jpg"
 }
```

The problem here is, if someone accidentally change the string "RightArrow.jpg" to "RghtArrow.jpg", it will not cause a compile time error. And it might take a lot of time to notice the run time error.

So is there any best practice here?
Of course I can build me own little mechanism for that... but I wander if there's anything build-in.

Something which is maybe strongly-typed fashioned:

```
img1.ImageUrl = Images.RightArrow;
```

Comment: You could use constants. You could also use embedded resources.

Comment: constants won't check if the file exist. of course i can make some mechanism which check every now and them whether or not all the constant are valid file names.. but i'm looking for something build-in.

Comment: Then what about embedded resources and app settings?

Comment: I don't know how to use it, i'm checking out now to see if it's good for me :)

Comment: Any function or piece of code that uses img1 should be making sure it exists in the directory before attempting to use it. You can then handle an exception and prompt an error or warning or whatever.

Comment: @JoshC. Hi. i couldn't find any example of using embedded resources in a strongly typed manner.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use Settings? If you did your code would be strongly typed, for example:

```
img1.ImageUrl = Settings.Default.Images.RightArrow
```

If you have a limited number of these resources this could be a good solution as you could even change the path/name without recompiling...

Comment: Not that this isn't a correct answer, but Images aren't really settings so should they really be put there? It seems misleading but if it works, it works. I would still go with @Sean Dunford's approach, though just use a struct instead. This allows you to place it in a spot that makes sense, both logically and inuitively

Comment: Yes, images are not settings, but deciding what image to display based on other variables or even user selected options (in a settings tab, for example) could surely be settings... Sean's approach will work, of course, but you'll end up with hard coded values that are not strongly typed...

Comment: @DeanK. is there any mechanism to check if the file exists?

Comment: @Letterman Yes, File.Exists Method http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Can you just keep a List of the names of the pictures?

```
List<string> CollectionPictureUri = new List<string>(); 
CollectionPictureUri.Items.Add("RightArrow.jpg"); 

if (success)
 {
    img1.ImageUrl = CollectionPictureUri[0]; 
 }
```

Or if you use a Map, then the key could just be `[RightArrow]`

Then you can initialize all the items in one block of code and make sure they are correct in one place.

EDIT:
You can also use asserts to validate that your strings resolve to the correct name. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.assert%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

There are other testing techniques that might be useful to you. With visual studio you can prevent your code from building until errors like this are resolved.

Comment: I was going to suggest a similar approach, if you define some sort of image struct you can set all the paths in one section of code. Then just use the 'interface' of your struct to access.

Comment: @AndrewHagner that's a good idea. I was going to say use a custom class but a struct seems more appropriate because of the minimal amount of helper functions he will probably need. It sounds like he just needs some sort of collection to aggregate all the extensions in one place.

Comment: this is exactly referring to "I can build my own little mechanism for that". This is a good possible solution, but i wander - does asp.net not support any build-in solution for that extremely common problem?

Comment: @Letterman what are you trying to avoid? Making sure the pictures exist in the file system? Or not using string literals for file URI? You can use the data type Path or URI to keep track of it.

Answer (score 1):

You could always use a T4 template to generate a class with constants for the files which actually exist. This is similar to what the T4 MVC template does for scripts and contents of the /Content directory; it scans those directories when it is run, and creates constants.